# System Thread Exception not handled error while updating to Windows 10 Feature update v1903

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update

I tried to update Windows 10 to Feature Update v1903. While running the update, I got the terrible blue screen "System Thread Exception not Handled" and was forced to restart. Fortunately, Windows 10 was smart to undo the changes and I was able to boot back to the old Windows 10.

When I checked the Event Viewer to see what is the problem, I saw this event "Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0xC1900101: Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903."

It seems to be a driver problem. I went to the motherboard's website and upgraded to the latest driver. Still the same problem. I am stuck. What else can I do? Please help. Thank you.

My hardware is gigabyte B450 Aorus pro wifi motherboard, AMD Ryzen 2700x CPU.

Comment: What was the sub-code of error 0xC1900101? Try to disconnect every possible device, disable VT-d in the BIOS, and try again from [installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10] .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

0xC1900101 error on the event viewer suggests that driver problems caused the windows upgrade to v1903 to fail. Natural next step would be to upgrade to the latest drivers for the motherboard.

On gigabyte website for the motherboard B450-AORUS-PRO-WIFI, the latest drivers for bluetooth and WiFi is written for Windows 10 v1809. The most logical explanation at this point is that the drivers for bluetooth and WiFi is causing the installation problem because they are not written to support v1903. I cannot verify if this is the exact cause until Gigabyte releases the drivers for Windows 10 v1903.

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10#support-dl-driver-wlanbt

I write this answer as reference. It may be helpful to other people who are having similar problems with Gigabyte B450-AORUS-PRO-WIFI motherboard.

Edit: I have finally solved the problem. 
The culprit was unexpected. After I **uninstall Avast Anti-virus software**, I am able to upgrade to v1903. I have also installed all the latest drivers of Gigabyte B450-AORUS-PRO-WIFI motherboard available on their websites.

Comment: @harrymc - This answer is very likely correct.  Gigabyte has released several updates for the B450 that specifically indicate 1903 support which is a different version that indicates support specifically for 1809.  I have to wait for my Killer Networking drivers to be updated to support a feature update before installing them.  This should not be a comment, it is far too detailed, to be a comment anyways

Comment: You can de-install the bluetooth device (maybe also the wifi, if you have a LAN cable or are willing to try it), and then install 1903.

Comment: Install this free application:  WhoCrashed. Run this utility to find out which driver is causing you SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED error. Then get rid of that driver.